# How to replace an existing value with another value through it's id in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

How do you put the value into the specific textfield of a particular row according to its index? My results only updates at the bottom or the last cell...

Currently it calls on itself for the current value. My only problem with this issue is that It will not update the current row but the last row of the index path.

[image]

.h file

//when label1 and label 2 are connected it causes the program to crash. Connection cannot have a prototype outlet as a destination

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label1; //not connected
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label2; //not connected


@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIStepper *stepper; // not conneted
-(IBAction)stepperChangedValue:(UIStepper *)sender; //connected to uistepper
```

.m file

```
-(IBAction)stepperChangedValue:(UIStepper *)sender{

//my incremental number is here
NSInteger i = [sender value];
NSLog(@"value: %i",i);
UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ];



//find row #
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
NSLog(@"value: %i",indexPath.row); //I have my row index here


//How do I put my sender value back into the correct row of my table?
}

// Return number of sections in table (always 1 for this demo!)
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [myData count];
}

// Return the amount of items in our table (the total items in our array above)
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [myData count];
}

// Return a cell for the table
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // A cell identifier which matches our identifier in IB
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StepperCell";

    // Create or reuse a cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Get the cell label using it's tag and set it
    UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    [cellLabel setText:[myData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    // get the cell label using it's tag and set it
    UILabel *cellLabel2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    [cellLabel2 setText:@"0"];

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks guys! I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's very unclear what you're asking. You have left out significant context. Also the written explanation of your problem doesn't clearly match with the comments in your code. If you're this fried, take a nap, or go for a walk, clear your head, whatever it takes, and read your question from the perspective of a stranger on the internet who has no idea about your context, and edit it until it's understandable from that perspective. Good luck!

Comment: lol I've been sitting in front of my computer for the past 18 hours... I restructured the question. Please help T.T

Comment: OMG.. you have totally missing the logic and blown up the code. Why are you setting the @"0" in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method? Please Read the UITableView Documentation to know how to use it. Or see some tutorial..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)stepperChangedValue:(UIStepper *)sender{

   //find row #
   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
   NSLog(@"value: %i",indexPath.row); //I have my row index here

    //my incremental number is here
    NSInteger i = [sender value];
    NSLog(@"value: %i",i);
   cell.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]; // textField is an outlet for your textfield in your cell

}
```

Your code should be like this. You need to change the text of the `textfield` after you get the `cell`. And in your code , you are changing the text for the `textfield` with `tag 2` and last `cell` `textfield` may have `tag 2`. So it causes the problem too.

Comment: Not working out for me... The textfield isn't working out.
Property not found on object of type UITableViewCell

I am aware that every row has a tag 2... since it is dynamically generated.... But using the code I have I am not able to work with the tag 2?

I just want tot put the sender value back into the field of the tag id at that particular row index when I increment or decrement the value

Comment: Then you need to show what you are doing in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.. I already gave the comment line before the textfield line in my code. Read that. Its an outlet for a textfield property. If you don't have property, then good to add. Otherwise set the indexpath.row as tag for your textfield in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. But it will lead to a problem in some way

Comment: Okay I just edited my question with my cellforrowatindexpath. Also I'd like to mention that my Labels are not connected. Whenever I connect the IBOutlet to it, it will give me a "Connection cannot have a prototype outlet as a destination" :/

Comment: You are resetting the cellLabel2 every time: [cellLabel2 setText:@"0"];  Remove that and @R.A.'s solution should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `UITableViewCell` class. Declare `label`, `outlet` and `action` methods from each class.

**customcell.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_title;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *stepper;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_value;

- (IBAction)stepper:(UIStepper *)sender;
```

**customcell.m**

```
- (IBAction)stepper:(UIStepper *)sender {
NSUInteger value = sender.value;

 lbl_value.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];


}
```